# JIRA access using REST API decompressing data error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to work with JIRA API using python. I've used sample from this page **https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/python/185/jira-python-rest.html**

and in general it worked before I changed filter from

> project = PKY
>   to 
>   project = INN and type=Epic

I receving following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 388, in _decode
    data = self._decoder.decompress(data)   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 85, in decompress
    ret += self._obj.decompress(data) zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 750, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 536, in read
    data = self._decode(data, decode_content, flush_decoder)   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 391, in _decode
    raise DecodeError( urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/work/py/jirafirst/1.py", line 21, in <module>
    response = requests.request(   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 686, in send
    r.content   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 828, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''   File "D:\work\py\jirafirst\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 755, in generate
    raise ContentDecodingError(e) requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check'))
```

sample

```
import requests
import json
import base64

# Base encode email and api token
cred =  "Basic " + base64.b64encode(b'myemail@otg.com:pQcIDzMucUS76VBUmwzp2012').decode("utf-8") 
# Set header parameters
headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Authorization" : cred
}

# Enter your project key here
projectKey = "PKY"

# Update your site url 
url = "https://mysite.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=" + projectKey

# Send request and get response
response = requests.request(
   "GET", 
   url,
   headers=headers
)

# Decode Json string to Python
json_data = json.loads(response.text)

# Display issues
for item in json_data["issues"]:
    print(item["id"] + "\t" + item["key"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["issuetype"]["name"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["created"]+ "\t" +
        item["fields"]["creator"]["displayName"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["status"]["name"] + "\t" +
        item["fields"]["summary"] + "\t" 
        )
```

Comment: See my comment at the end of that article

Comment: actually I started with JIRA library and got same error. than I tried to do in directly without using this library and got same error. I think that it is becouse of some JIRA settings since another JIRA which I could access works well without errors.

Answer (score 0):

solved this by puting `'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'` in headers of request.
same approach works for JIRA Library